# How to enable memory compression on SUSE 11/12?

Tags: suse, sles

How can we enable, fine-tune the Linux kernels memory compression?

So if we have 1 GByte physical memory, the OS could see ex.: 1.5 GByte because of the compression (but of course it would use more CPU).

Comment: That's not how it works. Compression doesn't increase available memory, it just decreases the space taken by what is stored in the memory. Your system will always see 1G of RAM, it just might be able to store >1G of data if the data are compressed.

Comment: that is ok now, thanks! But how do we enable it on SUSE 11/12?

Comment: it cannot be done from user perspective? :) need to re-compile the kernel, or what?

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/12-SP2/#fate-318957) might point you in the right direction. It tells you what to look up but not necessarily how to implement. I also believe there's a zram service you can install. Something like systemd-zram-service.